# problem about "that" / a conjunction? or r.pronoun?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, conjunctions

I've a problem in the following text, please help me.

> A *shroud* is a piece of cloth *that* a dead person's body is wrapped in before it is buried.

my problem is-  is *shroud* a proper noun? And what kind of *that* is it? Conjunction? R. pronoun?

Comment: That that is a "that clause" (one type of the defining relative clauses).

Answer (score 1):

Shroud is a noun (not proper).

"That" is a relative pronoun that introduces the restrictive relative clause that follows it.

Comment: what is restrictive  relative clause

Comment: read [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/relative-clauses), or search [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=english+relative+clause)  , or even [here](http://www.bing.com/search?q=english+relative+clause)

Answer (score 0):

In this context, 'shroud' is a common noun, but not a proper noun. The Turin Shroud would be a proper noun as it is a specifically named item, but here you could refer to any shroud.

A proper noun names something that is unique - John, New York, Madison Square Garden, the Mona Lisa.

A common noun could be any one of many things like this - man, city, place, thing.